# Grails doesn't update data object when a file is included in GSP form?

Tags: forms, grails, grails-orm, gsp

I'm a Grails newbie, but I thought I was doing ok until I started messing about with file uploads.  I'm trying to upload a file to S3 and store the file location in my data object.

My problem is I can upload a file fine, and I can update my data object fine, but for some crazy reason I can't do both at the same time!

Here's the simplified test code:

GSP Form:

```
<form method="post" url="[resource:fileBundleInstance, action:'test']" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="bundle">
     <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="test" value="Test" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@Transactional
def test(FileBundle fileBundleInstance) {

    def file = request.getFile('bundle')
    println file ? "found " + file.originalFilename : "no file"

    fileBundleInstance.state = "test"   // only works if no file input in form
    redirect (action:'edit', id: fileBundleInstance.id)
}
```

So this code gets the file just fine, but doesn't update the state of the FileBundleInstance.  However, if I comment out the file upload form element:

```
        <form method="post" url="[resource:fileBundleInstance, action:'test']" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <!--input type="file" name="bundle"-->
                <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="test" value="Test" />
        </form>
```

... suddenly the state gets updated fine (but of course I have no file)!

I suspect I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something here about how GSP forms work in grails - can anyone set me right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... embarrassingly this is my mistake :-/.

It turns out that the name I was using for my file, 'bundle', was also the name of a field in my data object.  Grails was throwing a data exception, and I didn't have good error handling (newbie, remember :-) ).

When I add lines:

```
 fileBundleInstance.save();
        fileBundleInstance.errors.allErrors.each {error ->
            println error.toString()}
```

I see my nice shiny error - and if I change the name from 'bundle' to 'myfile' everything works.  Oops.